# Editing on scroll position in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll, css-position

I have a site design where a second logo needs to appear after a set scroll position. I have managed this with the following code:

```
myID = document.getElementById("logoTwo");

var myScrollFunc = function () {
    var y = window.scrollY;
    if (y >= 300) {
        logoTwo.className = "logo-lines show"
    } else {
        logoTwo.className = "logo-lines hide"
    }  
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

Can I adapt this script so that when a user scrolls to a set point of the screen, the logo then stops being fixed position, and will scroll with screen with the rest of the content?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

look into using css `position:sticky` for the logo that needs to move out of the way after a set point, the logo element's position would be sticky, and the bottom of its parent container is where it would stop being fixed on screen. Position the bottom of the sticky element's parent at the point where you'd like the fixed position to stop, and the sticky element will scroll with the page.

For reference: https://alligator.io/css/position-sticky/